# After puppeteer v12 but size PDF generated by new version is drastically increased, why?

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I was using puppeteer v7 and upgraded to puppeteer v12 and PDF was generated after upgrading the puppeteer size if PDF is generated it drastically changes

before upgrading puppeteer, it was generating **3.5 MB** of PDF for 3MB of HTML

before upgrading puppeteer, it is generating **16 MB** of PDF for 3MB of HTML

Is it possible using setting any flag we can reduce the PDF size in new puppeteer, any other solution for small PDF generating

Comment: Should not one of "before" be "after"?

Comment: There are a lot of librairies out there that can shrink PDF sizes. You may want to try those.

Comment: V7 to V12 is a big difference! Maybe Puppeteer is building PDF files with more information in them - properly embedded fonts, extra metadata and so on. Give it a quick check with `cpdf -squeeze in.pdf -o out.pdf` to see if there is any obvious fat to trim.

Answer (score 0):

This is the chromium issue it is solved after chromium 104

to solve this you just need to set flag `--disable-pdf-tagging`

[chromium issue/solution](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1309963#c19)